# What's different about jenkins sshpublishers and ansible?

Tags: jenkins, ansible, jenkins-plugins, devops

I wanna use deploy tool with jenkins.

so I find two kinds deploy mehtods, ansible & ssh publishers.

I think that two things do the same thing.

can u explanation thats a diffrence?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a low level they're the same, they're for doing automation via ssh. Ansible has a bunch of strong ideas about structure, prebuilt modules for doing things reliably[1], and strong support for parallelism.

It really depends on how much you want to do here. If you want to do simple things for a small number of hosts, and you don't know Ansible, you might be happier with SSH publishers. If you have ambitions about lots of hosts, lots of deployments, etc., you should probably use Ansible.

[1]: even simple things like 'copying files' can have a bunch of tricky edge cases

Comment: Thanks Henry! I understand what you say. maybe I need to experience for varity environments and situations.